# Visual Studio Code (vscode) Constructor Snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code

in VS2015 Community I can use **ctor** to create a constructor inside my *class*.

How can I do this with VSCode in a Mac?

I have read about create my self and publish... but the documentation is not so clear for me... ([link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets))

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reproduce the exact behavior of `ctor` snippet from VS2015, you can't because VSCode isn't currently able to detect the class name.

So you will have to type the class name in your constructor :

```js
"Constructor": {
    "prefix": "ctor",
    "body": [
        "public $0() {",
        "\t$1",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "Create a constructor"
}
```

Comment: Please edit the code... @Guillaume ;) You need a " and , in the body second line ;)